# Create json object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I've tested my REST service with success using Advanced Rest Client, where I'm sending a payload that looks like this:

```
{
  "comments":"test comments",
  "internal_verification_areas":[
  {
     "area_id":"1",
     "selected":"1",
     "notes":"notes1",
     "status":"1"
  },
  {
     "area_id":"2",
     "selected":"0",
     "notes":"notes2",
     "status":"0"
  }]
}
```

As mentioned my REST function executes with success.

I then moved to implement the whole thing on my web-interface and created the internal_verification_areas object as follows:

```
var verification_areas = {
        internal_verification_areas: [
            {
                area_id:"1",  // no need to quote variable names
                selected:"1",
                notes:"noter",
                status:"1"
            },
            {
                area_id:"2",  // no need to quote variable names
                selected:"1",
                notes:"noter2",
                status:"1"
            }
        ]
    };
```

The whole thing is then fed into my request like this (comments parameter is fetched from a textarea):

```
$.post("createInternalVerification.php",{comments: $('textarea#korrigeringer').val(),internal_verification_areas: verification_areas}
```

createInternalVerification.php will json encode the data and request the service.

The problem is, that i get an error saying: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'area_id' cannot be null". I assume there is something wrong with my posted data, but i can't figure out what. From my POV my Advanced Rest Client payload looks similar to the payload i send from my web-interface.

EDIT:

I've noticed that the network tab (google chrome) shows some differences in my payload. I'm returning internal_verification_areas in my response to analyze the difference.

(MY WEB INTERFACE RECEIVES)
    {"error":false,"message":"Intern efterprovning oprettet","test":{"internal_verification_areas":[{"area_id":"1","selected":"1","notes":"noter","status":"1"},{"area_id":"2","selected":"1","notes":"noter2","status":"1"},{"area_id":"3","selected":"1","notes":"noter3","status":"1"}]}}

(ADVANCED REST CLIENT RECEIVES)
    {"error":false,"message":"Intern efterprovning oprettet","test":[{"area_id":"1","selected":"1","notes":"jAAAAAAA","status":"1","id":"4"},{"area_id":"2","selected":"0","notes":"NEEEEEJ","status":"0","id":"5"}]}

Comment: check what your actually send on the network tab - now your `internal_verification_areas` has the nested `internal_verification_areas`

Comment: @zerkms yes im returning my object in my response .. and you can see the difference in my edit of the post. Seems Rest Client has no "name" on my object.. dont know why

Comment: You have 2 nested `internal_verification_areas ` objects. `internal_verification_areas` must be an array, you send the object instead.

Comment: hmm .. how is that. I can see a variable called internal_verification_areas, but not two object. please elaborate :)

Comment: You can't have a json object. You can have a string containing json data, or you can have an object.

Comment: What type is the `verification_areas` variable in the second piece of code in the question? What type is the `internal_verification_areas` attribute in the very first piece of code in the question? Please answer both.

Comment: @zerkms i have an javascript object with an array of objects ? :-|

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hejevldjsse16ov/Screenshot%202015-04-20%2010.05.32.png?dl=0 In the first case it's an array, in the second it's an object. I have no idea why you think they are interchangeable.

Comment: In short: it's not obvious why you don't see the difference between `{a: [1,2,3]}` and `{a: {a: [1,2,3]}}`

Comment: ok i can see that now. Need to get my object and array syntax straight. Please submit and answer and i will accept it ..

Comment: so i guess i can change my web-interface as follows:
var internal_verification_areas = [{}, {}, {} /*, ... */];

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guess I messed up my understanding of objects and arrays. Turns out my web-interface was sending and array with and object with arrays. Changing it (as shown after this post) fixed my mistake. I'm so sorry zerkms for wasting your precious time and causing an immense annoyance to your unicum skilled mind. I find it more and more frightening to post questions on StackOverflow with the presence of such skilled and godlike figures who constantly remind minions such as myself that Stackoverflow has become the very bedrock of arrogant developers.

```
var internal_verification_areas = [
            {
                area_id:"1",  // no need to quote variable names
                selected:"1",
                notes:"noter",
                status:"1"
            },
            {
                area_id:"2",  // no need to quote variable names
                selected:"1",
                notes:"noter2",
                status:"1"
            },
            {
                area_id:"3",  // no need to quote variable names
                selected:"1",
                notes:"noter3",
                status:"1"
            }
        ];
```

Comment: So I helped you to become a better developer: not only you know how to debug better now, but I also let you solve your issue yourself (which made you a better specialist as well) and now you blame me? Well, thanks for calling me ignorant then.

Comment: @zerkms: You started out pointing me in the right direction, which is acceptable since i need to elaborate end find the solution to my problem myself, if possible. Later, instead of pointing out what i did wrong in relation to my understanding of the syntax for objects and arrays, you focus on my lack of knowledge and the fact that you cannot understand why I could not see the difference in my syntaxes. I DO NOT think one should request a solution on this page whithout having put enough effort into debugging the problem themselfs.

Comment: But my experience lately is, that the comments to questions on this page are more and more often loaded with an underlaying arrogance to the general lack of skills of others instead of a clean constructive dialog.

Comment: I focused on lack of attention, not knowledge. You just wasn't careful enough to compare 2 objects.

Comment: That attention could have been stated by simply making me aware, that I didnt construct my payload properly, and highligt what the difference of the payloads were. Not emphazise on why you cannot understand that i cannot see the difference.. I was'nt interested in your personal feelings towards my lack of understanding, but constructive feedback to make me understand ...